# using jquery and html form to show range value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have included the form in my website with sliders using the range input html form. Though the range do not show the actual value by default I found a script to show the display for example "bedrooms" and "bathrooms".

P.S. When I submit the form using php the values are different. Which is alright.

Hoping that the display shows individual "range-value" for each bedroom and bathroom sections rather than showing same values while the sliders are moving. Perhaps giving a separate variable for both of them can lead to individual output? How can i do this? Can anyone help with it?

```js
var range = $('.input-range'),
  value = $('.range-value');
value.html(range.attr('value'));
range.on('input', function() {
  value.html(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" target="formfill" action="form-to-email.php">
  
      <div class="field">
        <label for="Bedrooms">Bedrooms</label>
      </div>
      <div class="range-slider">
        <input class="input-range" type="range" value="1" min="0" max="10">
      </div>
      <span class="range-value"></span>
      <div class="field">
        <label for="bathrooms">Bathrooms</label>
      </div>
      <div class="range-slider">
        <input class="input-range" type="range" value="1" min="0" max="10">
      </div>
      <span class="range-value"></span>

</form>
```

Comment: Hi Wasi, welcome to stackover flow. I noticed that you are including far more code then is necessary to explain your problem. For example, most of the HTML and all of the CSS can be removed from the question. This makes it much easier for people to grasp what it is you are trying to ask.

Comment: oh ok I'll remove them thanks! I got the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
range.on('input', function() {
  // this sets the html content of all elements with class range-value
  // to the value of the slider that is being moved
  value.html(this.value);
});
```

The fix that I am showing simply moves the `span` tag into the div, this is just one way of knowing what `.range-value` belongs to witch slider.

Also since `value="1"` is hard coded into the range sliders, you can also just have the span tags start with the same value `<span class="range-value">1</span>`

```js
$('.input-range').on('input', function() {
  $(this).next('.range-value').html(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="input-range" type="range" value="1" min="0" max="10">
  <span class="range-value">1</span>
</div>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="input-range" type="range" value="1" min="0" max="10">
  <span class="range-value">1</span>
</div>
```

I have removed the CSS and most of the HTML from the answer as it is not relevant to the problem, but to see it working in the full form [**here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wsxs4xqw/)

Comment: It works like a charm by changing the class range-value to value of the slider. Thanks for the solution.